# How do I change the description of a view?

Tags: views, 8

I have some existing views for which I have written a developer guide description. Now I duplicated the views for some other task, Duplication is successful but I didn't find any possibilities to change the description of the view. I check advanced section of the view but not successful. 
The only way is to create a new view but it will take a lot of time and I already have it done in the existing views a few changes are required. But the description is different from the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit a view, on the top right corner there is an *Edit view name/description* button.

> [image: screenshot]